# Pushing Docker Image to Another Account's ECR from AWS Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to build a docker image from a Pipeline account and push it into the ECR of another account (Dev).

While I'm able to docker push from codebuild to an ECR repo within the same account (Pipeline), I'm having difficulty doing this for an external AWS account ECR.

The policy attached to the ECR repo on the Dev account:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowCrossAccountPush",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<pipelineAccountID>:role/service-role/<codebuildRole>"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

On my pipeline account, the service role running the build project matches the ARN on the policy above, and my buildspec contains the following snippet that pushes the image:

```
- $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 --registry-ids <DevAccount>)
- docker tag <imageName>:latest $ECR_REPO_DEV:latest
- docker push $ECR_REPO_DEV:latest
```

Codebuild is able to log into ECR successfully, but when it tries to actually push the image, I get:

```
*denied: User: arn:aws:sts::<pipelineAccountID>:assumed-role/<codebuildRole>/AWSCodeBuild-413cfca0-133a-4f37-b505-a94668201e26 is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:<DevAccount>:repository/<repo>*
```

Additionally, I've gone ahead and made sure that the IAM policy for role  (residing on the codepipeline account) has permissions for this repo:

```
 {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountRepo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:<DevAccount>:repository/sg-api"
}
```

I have little idea now on what I could be missing. The only thing that comes to mind is having the build run with a cross-account role but I'm not even sure that's possible. My goal is to have the build pipeline separate from the dev. account as I hear that's best practice.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried arn:aws:iam::<pipelineAccountID>:root into the Principal? just to get a picture where the issue occurs? if that works means that problem occurs in somewhere in the policy

Comment: Try to assume role?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of this and the error message above, the most common cause is that the ECR repository does not have a policy which would allow the CodeBuild IAM role to access it.

Please set this policy on the ECR Repo:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCrossAccountPush",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<dev acount>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html#IAM_allow_other_accounts

Please add this policy on the CodeBuild service role:

```
{
            "Sid": "CrossAccountRepo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:*",
            "Resource": "*"
}
```